# SQLAlchemy bidirectional many-to-many raising ArgumentError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, relationship

I've tried to establish a many-to-many relationship between two tables, User and Product, through a third table, Cart. Since the cart has additional data for each row I'm trying to use the association object pattern, but clearly there's something fundamental I'm not understanding. Here are the model declarations:

```py
class Cart(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'cart'
    product_id: Mapped[int] = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    selling_price: Mapped[Decimal] = mapped_column(Numeric(precision=6, scale=2), nullable=True)
    quantity: Mapped[int]
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship("Users", back_populates="product")
    product: Mapped["Product"] = relationship("Product", back_populates="user")


class User(BaseModel, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    lastname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(60), nullable=False)
    products: Mapped[list['Product']] = relationship("Cart", back_populates='user')

    def add_to_cart(self, product_id: int):
        item_to_add = Cart.insert().values(product_id=product_id, user_id=self.id)
        self.session.execute(item_to_add)
        self.session.commit()
        flash('Your item has been added to your cart!', 'success')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.firstname}','{self.lastname}', '{self.email}','{self.id}')"


class Product(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "product"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)
    price: Mapped[Decimal] = mapped_column(Numeric(precision=6, scale=2), nullable=True)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text(), nullable=False)
    users: Mapped[list['User']] = relationship("Cart", back_populates='product')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Product('{self.name}', '{self.price}')"
```

At one point in the code I execute this query:

```py
        q = select(User).where(User.email == form.email.data)
        user = conn.session.query(q).scalars().first()
```

Because the code is embedded in a web server the process doesn't terminate, but I see this traceback (*routes.py* is the file with the web view function in it) - I've wrapped the final line for reading convenience:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1458, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Users/sholden/Projects/Python/ecommerce/unwrap/routes.py", line 54, in login
    user = conn.session.query(q).scalars().first()
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2912, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 276, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 288, in _set_entities
    self._raw_columns = [
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 289, in <listcomp>
    coercions.expect(
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 442, in expect
    return impl._implicit_coercions(
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 506, in _implicit_coercions
    self._raise_for_expected(element, argname, resolved)
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 1137, in _raise_for_expected
    return super()._raise_for_expected(
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 710, in _raise_for_expected
    super()._raise_for_expected(
  File "/Users/sholden/.venvs/ecommerce-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 535, in _raise_for_expected
    raise exc.ArgumentError(msg, code=code) from err
  sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns
  clause element expected, got <sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x104c04d90>.
  To create a FROM clause from a <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select'> object, use the
  .subquery() method. (Background on this error at https://sqlalche.me/e/20/89ve)
```

I've tried various combinations of arguments to the `relationship` calls, but the documentation and other information on SQLAlchemy, while voluminous, is conflicting and often unhelpful and I've so far found no way to get the query to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `user = session.execute(q).scalars().first()` or the shorter form `user = session.scalars(q).first()`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Either change results in the following error "`InvalidRequestError
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'Mapper[Cart(cart)]' has no property 'users'.  If this property was indicated from other mappers or configure events, ensure registry.configure() has been called.`" Sounds like I may need to fix the relationships somehow ...